It is possible to set a title tab in django without to pass throught html?
Is it possible to set a page title in Django without going through the HTML file directly?
I have data stored in my object, and I want to extract the name to set it as the title in my template. Essentially, I generate my views and URLs dynamically from the backend using HTTP requests.
I'd like to know if there's a way to set the title dynamically without having to possess a .html file, as I generate my templates dynamically and don't have static .html files
I except to set a title tab without passing through a .html file just from the .py files

I am not sure but I think, you wanna render HTML directly within your view function in Django without using a separate template file. If that is the question you asked, you can do by using 'render()' function and pass HTML content as a String. Example -
from django.http import HttpResponse
def [your_view](request):
    html_string = "<html><head><title>Custom Page Title</title></head></html>"
    return HttpResponse(html_string)

But if you just want to pass title as String from view and show in html template, you can do like following:
In HTML Template File:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title> <!-- Dynamically set the page title -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML content goes here -->
</body>
</html>

In view.py:
from d
jango.shortcuts import render
from .models import YourModel

def [your_view](request):
    title = "your page title"
    
    # Pass the title to the template context
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'title': title})

Cheer!

Just in the generated template code under the <HTML> set the title as this
   <head>
   <title>TITLE</title>
   </head>


You can do it generically in your base.html or equivalent. Just edit it to
<head>
<title>{{my_page_title|default:'Default Title'}}</title>
</head>

and pass the variable my_page_title through the context of your views. Alternatively and easier, using Class-based views, do
<head>
<title>{{view.page_title|default:'Default Title'}}</title>
</head>

And then in your class-based view you can simply declare the title
 class MyView( FormView):
     page_title = 'My View title'
     ...

You can do something similar with {{form.page_title}} and you might combine all of these hierarchically using {%if ... %} to work out what is set.
